# Does the useEffect in a nested component cause the page to be rendered on the server side or the client side?

Tags: next.js

I am working on a **nextjs** app and I have a question about **render** a page that this page has a nested component that I used **useEffect** in this component and my page doesn't recive any data from server it's landing page, I want to know that **useEffect** will render page on the server side

```
import { useTheme } from "@emotion/react";
import { Box, Button, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Iphone from "../components/Iphone";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Tutorial from "../components/Tutorial";
import styles from "../styles/index.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          minHeight: "100vh",
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
        className={styles.container}
      >
        <Navbar elevation={0} />
        <Grid
          sx={{
            marginTop: theme.spacing(15),
            padding: "0 10px",
            [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
              marginTop: theme.spacing(20),
            },
          }}
          container
        >
          <Grid
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              width: "100%",
            }}
            item
            sm={12}
            lg={7}
          >
            <Typography
              align="right"
              sx={{
                fontSize: "2.2rem",
                [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
                  fontSize: "3rem",
                },
              }}
              color={theme.palette.custom.light}
              // variant="h4"
            >
              دفتر ثبت عملکرد برای کنکوری‌ها!
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                width: "50%",
                mt: theme.spacing(5),
                fontSize: "1.2rem",
                [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
                  width: "100%",
                },
              }}
              align="justify"
              color={theme.palette.custom.light}
              variant="body1"
            >
              با اپلیکیشن تراز میتونید برای خودتون به تفکیک روزهای هفته هدفگذاری
              کنید. بعدش ببینید چقدر از این هدف ها محقق شده و با توجه به این
              برنامه خودتون رو بهتر کنید. همچنین امکان مشاهده گزارش هفتگی،
              ماهانه و جامع (کل مطالعاتی که داشتید) هم وجود داره!
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", mt: theme.spacing(2) }}>
              <Button
                color={"light"}
                size="large"
                sx={{ fontSize: "18px", width: "200px" }}
                variant="outlined"
                onClick={() => {
                  document
                    .getElementById("download")
                    .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
                }}
              >
                دانلود!
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            sx={{
              [theme.breakpoints.down("lg")]: {
                width: "100%",
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                mt: theme.spacing(10),
                mb: theme.spacing(10),
              },
            }}
            item
            sm={12}
            lg={5}
          >
            <Iphone />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
      <Tutorial />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

and I used useEffect in **Navbar** component now this will render the Home page on the server side? thanks for help

```
import { useTheme } from "@emotion/react";
import {
  AppBar,
  Box,
  Container,
  Fade,
  IconButton,
  Toolbar,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Menu as MenuIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyledTypography } from "../CustomTheme/Theme";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Navbar(props) {
  const { custom } = props;
  const theme = useTheme();

  const router = useRouter();
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(
    typeof window === "undefined" ? 0 : window.innerWidth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true);
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    });
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
      setScroll(window.scrollY);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!showChild) {
    return null;
  }

  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <AppBar
      position="fixed"
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        backgroundColor:
          scroll > 10 ? theme.palette.custom.light : "transparent",

        color: custom
          ? theme.palette.custom.dark
          : scroll > 10
          ? theme.palette.custom.dark
          : theme.palette.custom.light,
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      <Container>
        <Toolbar>
          <Image
            width={150}
            height={30}
            src={
              custom
                ? require("../images/logo-type-dark.png")
                : scroll > 10
                ? require("../images/logo-type-dark.png")
                : require("../images/logo-type-light.png")
            }
          />

          <StyledTypography
            component={"div"}
            onClick={() => {
              document
                .getElementById("download")
                .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
            }}
            sx={{
              mr: 10,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: custom ? "none" : { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
              color:
                document.getElementById("download") &&
                document.getElementById("feature")
                  ? scroll >= document.getElementById("download").offsetTop &&
                    scroll < document.getElementById("feature").offsetTop
                    ? theme.palette.secondary.main
                    : ""
                  : "",
            }}
          >
            دانلود
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"div"}
            onClick={() => {
              document
                .getElementById("feature")
                .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
            }}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: custom ? "none" : { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
              color:
                document.getElementById("download") &&
                document.getElementById("feature")
                  ? scroll >= document.getElementById("feature").offsetTop &&
                    scroll < document.getElementById("detail").offsetTop
                    ? theme.palette.secondary.main
                    : ""
                  : "",
            }}
          >
            ویژگی ها
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"div"}
            onClick={() => {
              document
                .getElementById("about")
                .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
            }}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: custom ? "none" : { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
              color: document.getElementById("about")
                ? scroll >= document.getElementById("about").offsetTop
                  ? theme.palette.secondary.main
                  : ""
                : "",
            }}
          >
            درباره ما
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"a"}
            href={"#"}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
            }}
            onClick={() => router.push("/blog")}
          >
            وبلاگ
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"a"}
            href={"#"}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
            }}
            onClick={() => router.push("/school")}
          >
            پنل آموزشگاه
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"a"}
            href={"#"}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
            }}
            onClick={() => router.push("/app")}
          >
            وب اپلیکیشن
          </StyledTypography>

          <StyledTypography
            component={"a"}
            href={"#"}
            sx={{
              mr: 3,
              fontSize: "16px",
              cursor: "pointer",
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
            }}
            onClick={() => router.push("/advisor")}
          >
            مشاور
          </StyledTypography>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "none",
              [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
                display: "flex",
                flexGrow: 1,
              },
            }}
          ></Box>
          <Fade in={width < 900} {...(width < 900 ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              sx={{
                mr: 2,
                display: width < 900 ? "flex" : "none",
                alignSelf: "flex-end",
              }}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Fade>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` only gets executed on components mount, on the client-side. It does not run during server-side rendering.

Answer (score 1):

From [Client-side data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side) documentation:

> If done at the page level, the data is fetched at runtime, and the
> content of the page is updated as the data changes. When used at the
> component level, the data is fetched at the time of the component
> mount, and the content of the component is updated as the data
> changes.
>
> It's important to note that using client-side data fetching can affect
> the performance of your application and the load speed of your pages.
> This is because the data fetching is done at the time of the component
> or pages mount, and the data is not cached.

Long story short: `useEffect` will execute Client side

Comment: if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return <></>;

In your code doesn't has any impact at all

Comment: I used this because when window has used in Navbar component and when page will render on the sever it gives error for window object

Comment: Yes because the window object is only available on the client

Comment: in your opinion my page (Home) will render on  the server or client?

Comment: Because you don't fetch data and don't have blocking ressources it will be rendered staticly.
Next.js automatically determines that a page is static (can be prerendered) if it has no blocking data requirements. This determination is made by the absence of getServerSideProps and getInitialProps in the page. 
But the useEffect hook will only work on client side.

Comment: it's means Home will render on the server . it's right?
but component Navbar will render on the client beacuse it used useEffect in it